# How to verify entire content of Geb module using Spock at once without asserting each element individually?

Tags: module, spock, assertions, geb, presentation-layer

I have a Module with content defined for each element on the webpage I am working with:

```
package com.abc.modules

import geb.Module

class Member extends Module {
    static content = {
        // Member fields
        mbrID {$("div.subject-details div.memberDetails input.projMbrId")}
        mbrName {$("input.projMbrName")}
        mbrRegion {$("select.projMbrReg")}
        mbrAdd1 {$("input.projMbrAdd1")}
        mbrAdd2 {$("input.projMbrAdd2")}
        mbrAdd3 {$("input.projMbrAdd3")}
        mbrCity {$("input.projMbrCity")}
        mbrState {$("select.projMbrState")}
        mbrZip {$("input.projMbrZip")}
        mbrHomePhone {$("input.projMbrHomePhone")}
        mbrHomePhoneExt {$("input.projMbrHomePhoneExt")}
        mbrWrkPhone {$("input.projMbrWorkPhone")}
        mbrWrkPhoneExt {$("input.projMbrWorkPhoneExt")}
        mbrEmail {$("input.projMbrPersonalEMail")}
        mbrWrkEmail {$("input.projMbrWorkEMail")}
    }
}
```

In my test spec I am asserting that each element contained in my module is present, but the only way I know how to do it is by asserting each element individually:

```
package cmdr.ProjectCover

import com.gdit.qa.fwa.geb.cmdr.pages.HomePage
import com.gdit.qa.fwa.geb.cmdr.pages.ProjectCover
import geb.spock.GebReportingSpec

class VerifyMemberFields extends GebReportingSpec {
    def setupSpec() {
        // Log in to app
        via HomePage
        loginPage.signIn("marco", "abc123")

        // Navigate to Member Page
        memberPageButton.click()
    }

    def "Verify Member fields exist"() {
        when: "User selects Member option for subject type"
        at ProjectCover
        projSubject.click()
        projCoverMbrFields.projSubjectMbrOption.click()

        then: "All expected member fields are displayed in the left panel"
        assert projCoverMbrFields.mbrID.present
        assert projCoverMbrFields.mbrName.present
        assert projCoverMbrFields.mbrRegion.present
        assert projCoverMbrFields.mbrAdd1.present
        assert projCoverMbrFields.mbrAdd2.present
        assert projCoverMbrFields.mbrAdd3.present
        assert projCoverMbrFields.mbrCity.present
        assert projCoverMbrFields.mbrState.present
        assert projCoverMbrFields.mbrZip.present
        assert projCoverMbrFields.mbrHomePhone.present
        assert projCoverMbrFields.mbrHomePhoneExt.present
        assert projCoverMbrFields.mbrWrkPhone.present
        assert projCoverMbrFields.mbrWrkPhoneExt.present
        assert projCoverMbrFields.mbrEmail.present
        assert projCoverMbrFields.mbrWrkEmail.present
    }
```

I am wondering if there is a way for me to (instead of asserting each element of my module individually) assert the entire content of the module at once so that my feature method then block conditions can be reduced.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a way to do it at the moment but it will be possible and relatively easy when [GEB-369](https://github.com/geb/issues/issues/369) is implemented.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have time to test this, but I think this should work if you want to give it a try:

```
def "Verify Member fields exist"() {
    when: "User selects Member option for subject type"
    at ProjectCover
    projSubject.click()
    projCoverMbrFields.projSubjectMbrOption.click()

    then: "All expected member fields are displayed in the left panel"
    projCoverMbrFields.content.each{ element ->
        assert element.present
    }
}
```